# How do I find a constant $C$, when $x = a$, through the tangent line?

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

The full question is as follows:

For some constant $C$, the equation of the tangent line to the graph of

$y = f(x)$ = $4x^4$+C

at the point where $x=a$ is

$y = −78.608x − 106.1252$

Find $C$.

My teacher does not go by the textbook, and I can't find any information online, so I'm completely stuck on how to solve this

Comment: What does  $f(x) = 4x4$ mean? Should it be $4x^4$?

Comment: Hi! Please typeset your mathematics using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Doing so will help keep your answer from being poorly received. Of course, MathJax has a learning curve, but if you make an honest initial attempt, experienced users will generally be happy to help you improve and fix whatever errors you experience. ¶ For example, `$4x^4$` yields $4x^4$.

Comment: @AlgTop1854 yes, I just corrected it, and that's the issue, I don't know what a is, that's quote on quote the problem

Comment: Hint: The slope of the tangent line is...

Comment: More hints (this group is trying hard not to do this for you): You are given the tangent line so you know its slope and intercept.  How do these relate to $f(x)$? Which of these will help you find $C$? Note that $a$ is **not** given - what does that mean?

Comment: @AlgTop1854, what I can't make sense of is the x = a part of it. With a definitive x value, I would find the corresponding y-value, take the derivative, then find the value of $f'(x)$ at whatever x was, and then plug all the points and the slope back in. What I don't understand is how the x=a part works, and I can't find the answer anywhere. Any pointers on that?

Comment: Try this: You KNOW the slope of the tangent line at $x=a$.  Now go back to $f(x)$ and think: if I want to get the slope of the tangent line at $x=a$, how do I do that, and try to write down the resulting equation - that **might** suggest how to get $a$ which you need to get to $C$.  In your comment, you actually have it, this problem feels tricky because it's the usual process somewhat backwards.

Comment: @AlgTop1854 I think I know what you mean, so here's what I did. I figured that if $x=a$, then I could replace all the x's with a's, giving the equation $f(x) = 4a^4$. I then took the derivative and got $f'(x)=16a^3$, to which we know that $f'(x)=-78.608$, so then I find the cubed root to get a. After this I can just use the normal procedure to get the value of C, correct?

Comment: Yes. The notation is a little bollixed up, so you mean $f'(x)=16x^3$ and then $f'(a)=-78.608$ which does give you $a$.  Where you write $f(x)=4a^4$ you mean $f(a)$ but where is $C$? With $a$ now you should be able to finish.  You can edit your question again with the solution and ask if correct (if you want to).

Comment: @AlgTop1854 Sounds good, just answered with what I believe it to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I believe the answer to be, but confirmation that it is correct would be helpful.

1. The original equation is $f(x) = 4x^4 + C$
2. As $x=a$, this can be written as $f(a) = 4a^4 + C$
3. Take the derivative of $f(a)$, giving $f'(a) = 16a^3$
4. $f'(a)$ is simply the slope of the tangent line, which can be used to create the equation $-78.608 = 16a^3$, which, when solved, gives $a = -1.7$
5. Now that $a$ is known, plug it back into the original equation to give the equation $f(a)=4(-1.7)^4+C$
6. Further, because a graph and its tangent line at a specific point are equal at that point, the following equation can be made: $-78.608(-1.7)-106.1252 = 4(-1.7)^4 + C$
7. Solve the equation for C, and C = -5.9

Comment: Yes, that's it. Good job!